# How to call a function returned from a custom React Hook?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, function, react-hooks

I am trying to create a React Hook that checks to see if the value a user inputs is unique. However first, the hook return value of 'isUnique' is not a function but rather an object with a function nested at the first index. and Second when calling the function I get an error "*Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.*"

Where am I going wrong?

```
export const useCheckUnique = (
  items: object[],
  param: keyof typeof self,
  self: number | string,
) => {
    const { showToast } = useSnack();
  const isUnique = (current) => {
    const inUse = items.some((x) => x?.[param] === current && x?.id !== self);
  if (inUse) {
        showToast({
          text: `wizard:${param}_NOT_UNIQUE`,
          variant: 'danger',
        });
      return false;
    } else {
      return true;

    }
  };
  return isUnique;
};
```

data will look like this

```
const items = [{id:1, value: 2}, {id:2, value:7}, {id:3, value: 9}];
const item = {id:2, value:7};
```

to assign:

```
const isAvailable = CheckUnique(items, 'value', item)
```

to use:

```
   <EntityFieldsetItem
          title="ewxample"
          value={value}
          update={(x) => {
              const canUpdate = isAvailable(x)
              if (canUpdate) {
                //update
               }

           }}
        />
```

Comment: How does CheckUnique class does it look like? You need that class to be a React Component at least to use hooks.

Comment: i think it is beacuse you are never triggering the isUnique function. so you don't get the result of it but what it contains, wich is a function.